# Ajax: php part requires quotes in one function but not in another

Tags: php, ajax

I have two different functions which both do Ajax calls.

In the first one I am assigning a string to the variable data: the part where I insert php Session variables is not in quotes

```
function insertMemberActivities()
{
    var data = "memId=" + <?php echo $_SESSION['memberId'];?> + "&acts=" + <?php echo $_GET['actID'] ;?> + "&comments=" + document.getElementById('comments').value;

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'json-responses.php?fct=insertMemberActivities',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: sendMailToMember(),
        // error: myCallbackError
    });
};
```

In the second one which looks similar however I have to add quotes around the php parts or otherwise it is not working

```
function sendMailToMember()
{
    var data = "eventName=" + "<?php echo $_GET['eventName'];?>" +
               "&userEmail=" + "<?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ;?>" + 
               "&first=" + "<?php echo $_SESSION['first']; ?>" + 
               "&last=" + "<?php echo $_SESSION['last']; ?>";

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'stcg-json-responses.php?fct=emailSendToVolunteer',
        data: data,
        cache: false
    });
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why that could be?

Comment: So the seconds one successfully sends the value of Session despite the fact that the PHP tags etc. are a string? Puzzling... not sure why the second one would work for you properly tbh

Comment: Are they both in PHP files (I presume so)?

Comment: yes, they are in the same php file, and all the 4 variables are sent correctly, but as soon as I take away the quotes it does not work. the first function works with or without

Comment: for a moment I thought it could be linked to the fact that the two variables from the 1st function (memberId and actID) are numbers but when I replace memberID by first (from the second function) it also works without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

some of the variables consist of only characters and numbers. those do not need quotes

others have special characters like @ or . or spaces. in that case the  expression has to be between quotes.